# Methods behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on this note app and somehow the 
**clearstorage()  **
   Method is running on page Load...
    Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.

```
        function clearStorage()
        {
            alert('Clearing local Storage')

            localStorage.clear();
        }

// Ckear All Notes

window.onload=init();

// Add Sticky to Page

function addStickyToPage(value) {
    var sticky = document.createElement("li");
    sticky.setAttribute("class", "sticky");
    var t = document.createTextNode(value);
    sticky.appendChild(t); // Similar To Inner Html
    document.getElementById("postItNotesList").appendChild(sticky);
}



// CLEAR storage


// Create and get Sticky Note into the localStorage
function createSticky() {
    var value = document.getElementById("note_text").value;
    var key = "sticky_" + localStorage.length;
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    addStickyToPage(value);
}



function init() {

    var button = document.getElementById("add_button");
    button.onclick = createSticky;


    // Clear localStorage
    var clear_Btn = document.getElementById("clr_btn");
    clear_Btn.onclick = clearStorage();





    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        if (key.substring(0, 6) == "sticky") {
            var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
            addStickyToPage(value);
        }
    }


}
```

Please tell me where I am doing it wrong.
On Init function I have added a click handler but why is it running on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use perentheses when assigning event handlers, because this way you implicitly call the function. For example, you have `clear_Btn.onclick = clearStorage();`, but you should really just have `clear_Btn.onclick = clearStorage;`.

And this is why your function is called on load.

Also, remove the perentheses from `window.onload=init();`.

Comment: They're called 'perentheses' or 'parens' for short. Brackets are those: `[]`
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Comment: Have edited the answer accordingly. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

try by ..

```
 window.onload=init;
```

and replace the

```
 clear_Btn.onclick = clearStorage();
    // to 
 clear_Btn.onclick = clearStorage;
```

and [HERE](https://thechamplord.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/using-javascript-window-onload-event-properly/) is the link to get more knowledge about this..